# reindex elasticsearch if insert new elements into array of document

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I am new in `elasticsearch`. I have following type of structure into my ES.

```
PUT /my_index/blogpost/1
 {
 "title": "Nest eggs",
  "body":  "Making your money work...",
  "tags":  [ "cash", "shares" ],
  "comments": [ 
  {
   "name":    "John Smith",
   "comment": "Great article",
    "age":     28,
  "stars":   4,
  "date":    "2014-09-01"
  },
  {
  "name":    "Alice White",
  "comment": "More like this please",
  "age":     31,
  "stars":   5,
  "date":    "2014-10-22"
  }
 ]
}
```

I found documents are immutable: they cannot be changed, only replaced. So I want to know when I push or pull any object from "comments" array then what will happen? Will `my_index` will be reindexed or `1` document will be reindexed?

Comment: What do you mean by "pull", especially how pulling data from Elasticsearch would involve a reindexing? How do you intend to do the "push", is it using `update_by_query`? Can you give an example? Lastly, as reindex implies, an index is reindexed, so what do you mean by "1 document will be reindexed"?